# Existence of function with a hard derivative.

Tags: calculus

I had the question: does there exist diferentiable function $\;f(x)\;$ in the reals such that for $\;x\neq 0\;$ we have

$$f'(x)=\frac{e^{1/x}+1}{e^{1/x}}$$

I know that $\;f'(0)\;$ exists because it is given, but the limit above doesn't exist when $\;x=0\;$ because

$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{e^{1/x}+1}{e^{1/x}}=\infty$$

and from the other side the limit is one. I know that for diffferentiable function, all the points of discontinuity of his derivative functions are of the second kind and the above then is fine, but then I cannot answer the question.

We have not studied already the integral and antiderivative in the course, though I know a little of it from high school, but I think this $\;\int f'\;$ is very hard and I can't do it even if I could use integrals. I think the answer is no because I don't think they expect we know how to calculate $\;f(x)\;$
Thank you for answers and clues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Derivatives have the intermediate value property: if $F$ is differentiable on $[a, b]$, then $F'$, on $[a, b]$ takes on every value between $F'(a)$ and $F'(b)$.

Suppose that a function $f$ with the derivative you wrote really did exist.

Look at $a = -\frac{1}{\ln 3}$; there, you have
$$
f'(a) = \frac{e^{-\ln 3} + 1}{e^{-\ln 3}} = \frac{4/3}{1/3} = 4.
$$
For values $x$ between $a$ and $0$, $f'(x)$ will be even larger than 4.

But for $b = \frac{1}{\ln2}$, you'll have 
$$
f'(b) = \frac{e^{\ln 2} + 1}{e^{\ln 2}} = \frac{3}{2}.
$$
And at no point between $a$ and $b$ will you have $f'(x) = 2$, for example.

So the imagined function $f$ cannot exist, by the theorem above.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\phi(x)=1+e^{-1/x}$, $x\ne0$, $\phi(0)=0$. If $x>0$ then $1<\phi(x)<2$. On the other hand $\lim_{x\to0^-}\phi(x)=+\infty$. Let $a>0$ be such that $\phi(x)>2$ if $-a\le x<0$. Then $\phi$ does not have the mean value property on $[a,\infty)$ and therefore it is not the derivative of any differentiable function.